# Why might write speed on NIC be fraction of read speed?

Tags: network-adapter, speed

I have 2 servers (Windows 2008 R2)  each with an x710-DA2 NIC, cross-connected by a 10Gbps wire.

I can read a hard dive of one machine, from the other, at 250 MegaBytes/Sec, but the write speed is only 20 MegaBytes/Sec.

The same is true if I try the experiment from the other server.

What might be causing the write speed to be so slow?

Additional

Here is code I use to test. Just change fileURL to point at different drives.

```
public void Go()
{
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        lines.Add( "a whole line of text");
    }

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    string fileURL = @"C:\test.txt";
    //string fileURL = @"\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\ShareName\test.txt";

    textBox1.AppendText("\nTest file URL: " + fileURL + "\n");

    int n = 5000;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(fileURL, lines.ToArray<string>());
    }

    sw.Stop();

    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileURL);

    double speed = (fi.Length * n) / (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds * 1000000);

    textBox1.AppendText("Write test Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("f2") + " MegaBytes/Second: " + speed.ToString("f2") + "\n");

    sw.Restart();

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        var inLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileURL);
    }

    sw.Stop();

    speed = (fi.Length * n) / (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds * 1000000);

    textBox1.AppendText("Read test Elapsed:  " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("f2") + " MegaBytes/Second: " + speed.ToString("f2") + "\n");

    //Console.WriteLine("");

}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried reproducing the issue from the local system without the NIC involved?

Comment: Yes. I can test against any drive. and for my local c drive I get similar speeds for both read and write of +200 MB/s. See code I use added to question